# SQL Server query to calculate balance account for suppliers

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 5 tables in my database

[image]

I want my SQL Server query can run like this:

[image]

But I don't know how can I get that, So Please help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select s.SupnName,
    TotalPurchase = (select sum(p.Qntty * p.PurchsePrice)
                       from ProductsTble p
                      where p.supid = s.supid),
    TotalPayement = (select sum(c.Cashvalue)
                       from CashMovementTbl c
                      where c.supid = s.supid)
  from SuppliersTble s;
```

Make sure you have indexes `ProductsTble(supid)` and `CashMovementTbl(supid)`